# Google App Script Regex

Tags: xml, regex, google-apps-script

I am using the following code in Google app script to extract a number.

```
function getBTC_ZAR_ExchangeRate() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://coinmill.com/rss/BTC_ZAR.xml")
  var xmlText = response.getContentText();
  //var funded = Xml.parse(htmlText, true);
  var rate = xmlText.match(/BTC =\s(.*?)\sZAR<br/);    
  return rate[1];
}
```

I get an array with two items as a result. Only the second item in the array is the correct one.

```
result = {"BTC = 27.45 ZAR<br", "27.45"}
```

What am I doing wrong, because this cannot be the way it is suppose to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. [See the first example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). The values returned from match are 1. the pattern that you matched (you told it to match that whole thing, so it did; 2. followed by the value(s) from that pattern matched (in your case 27.45).

Comment: So is there a correct way of only getting the one correct answer I want?

Comment: [You can read about a similar quesetion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex). All solutions I have seen involve getting the second element. You can safely assume that `[1]` will not return an error if there is a match.

Answer (score 0):

As Phil Bozak answered, this is how match works. But this is a JavaScript function and has nothing to do otherwise with Google Apps Script specifically.